# How to dynamically load html code in an angular web app?

Tags: html, angular, web

I am building an angular web site that is about a book.

In a section, you could choose a chapter and get an excerpt of the chapter (excerpt is in html format).

I am wondering how I could store those excerpts. I thought it would be a bad idea to create a component for each chapter. I thought about storing the html in a string variable but I couldn't do that because the excerpt html code contains a lot of quotes (") and that makes impossible to set a string variable. Then I thought about creating many html files and to load the right one in the same component, but I can't figure how to dynamically load a html file in a component.

If you have any idea for a proper solution, please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Creating HTML files for each chapter and loading them upon selection is really a bad idea. As you've mentioned you don't wish to go for component creation, you can try Angular's `ngTemplateOutlet`. If all the chapters have the same common display template, your work is almost over by just defining a template in the component you are working, and display the right one by passing the appropriate chapter details. Here's a good [read](https://dev.to/frederikprijck/reusable-html-in-angular-using-ngtemplateoutlet-3l8p).

A sample usage of ng-template

```html
<ng-template #sampleTemplate let-item>
      <p>I am chapter {{ item.name }}</p>
</ng-template>
```

Below is where your chapters will be, say it's a list. You pass it's object (which contains details about that chapter) to the template above.

```html
<div *ngFor="let chapter of chapters">
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="sampleTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: chapter }">
        </ng-container>
 </div>
```

If you wish to display the chapter one at a time (say on click), you don't even have to go to template concepts, but just storing the chapter object in a variable on-click helps. Here's an example:

```html
<div *ngFor="let chapter of chapters; let i=index">
      <button type="button" (click)="selectedChapter=chapter">Open Chapter{{i+1}}</button><br><br>
 </div>

<div>
  <p>I am {{ selectedChapter.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Just define the variable `selectedChapter` in the typescript file.

```js
selectedChapter: any = this.chapters[0]; // chapters is the array of objects containing chapter details
```

Comment: I think this is not really what I wanted to do.I have a web page with links to all chapters. If you click on a chapter's link, it will open a page with an excerpt of the chapter. The excerpt is a text in html format. So the chapters share nothing in common except it is all text. Also I was wondering how to store the excerpts since they will contain a lot of quotes so I can't assign them to a string variable because of the quotes. So I don't see how I can have the chapters in form of a list. Tell me if there's something I don't understand correctly...

Comment: My few cents here.. Opening a new page upon click won't be a good idea in Angular. I have posted the answer as you wished to display details on the same component. By the way, how do you currently get the excerpt? If its a Json response, you could easily make use of innerHTML along with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response_object)) to achieve this.

Comment: The excerpts are in html code... with a lot of html tags. Also, there are a lot of quotes ("). I really don't know how to store the excerpts. Do you have an idea? Please tell me if you have! :) There are a lot of quotes in the excerpts. I guess I should escape the quotes but that would be very long because the excerpt are about 500 words long. So I don't know yet how to get the excerpt; it depends how they will be stored.

Comment: Hi @andremarquis , you do not have to worry about quotes as you'll get those escaped automatically if the response is JSON. Anything you get from database will be coming as a string. So just check the database response through console.log or something, and you will see those quotes being escaped automatically :)